# Bootstrap 5.2 : Collapsing issues with Webpack and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, bootstrap-5

I am working on a project using HTML, SASS and JS with Webpack 5.74.0.

I want to use Bootstrap 5 to make collapsable, a feature I just did. Because I couldn't make it work, I tried to just copy/paste the example from the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse) to see what was wrong.
Here's the example :

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-bs-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the template feature of Webpack's `html-loader` ([doc](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader)) to insert the HTML file in the page with JS : 

webpack.config :

```
module: {
    rules: [
       ...
       {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
       }
      ]
     }
```

The JavaScript code drawing the page :

```
import collapseExample from '../templates/collapseExample.html'

...

body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',collapseExample)
//collapseExample being a string from the source code
```

When building, the page shows the two buttons from the example, and `div#collapseExample` is hidden. This bit of code is the exact same from the example of the documentation, so I don't think `html-loader` is at fault here.
However **when I click either of the buttons, nothing happens**. No error in the console, and `div#collapseExample` is not showing up at all. I had exactly the same problem when trying with my own code (being the feature is well hidden, but nothing happens when I click the button).
I built both using the local server (`webpack serve --open --config {my Webpack config file}`), and when Webpack puts the build files in dist. The issue remains the same. I am using up to date Firefox.
What's wrong with what I am trying to do ? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try manually initializing the collapsible? maybe it's added after bootstrap adds its listeners.

```js
const bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse('#myCollapse', {
  toggle: false
})
```

Lets try also, on the `click` event of the buttons (for debugging purposes)

```js
var bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse('#collapseExample', {
  toggle: false
})
bsCollapse.toggle()
```

Comment: Where do I put this ? I tried as a global variable just after the import of the template and I get this error in the console : `this._config is undefined`

Comment: Ok it works ! Had to add the bsCollapse declaration just after adding the collapse section. Thanks !